# Regex to find lines containing numbers, starting with text, but removing text from the ocurrence

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Having the following input:

```
Testing 42702434884 
Testing 064352729-13
05.994.401/0001-53
Testing 134.632.125-03
```

I am trying to get lines containing numbers, considering only lines starting with text, and removing the text from the result,

Currently I tried the following expression:

```
(?!a-zA-Z)\b(\d{11}|\d{14})|(\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\-\d{2}|\d{3}\d{3}\d{3}\-\d{2})|(\d{2}\.\d{3}.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{2}\d{3}\d{3}\d{4}-\d{2})\b
```

I was able to remove the text from the result, and find lines containing the patterns, but could not filter only lines starting with text. [Here is the result](http://regexr.com/4qdaa) as example

How can I filter lines starting with text while removing the text from the result?

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Do you mean like this?  `^[a-zA-Z]+ (?:(?:\d{11}|\d{14})|(?:\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\-\d{2}|\d{3}\d{3}\d{3}\-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}\.\d{3}.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{2}\d{3}\d{3}\d{4}-\d{2})\b)` https://regex101.com/r/wVfvSw/1

Comment: @nullptr You can make the first part optional if you want https://regex101.com/r/d5xVYA/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the negative lookahead `(?!a-zA-Z)\b` with the pattern you tried is always true as what follows is a digit so it can be omitted.

Instead of using the negated lookahead `(?!a-zA-Z)` you can use an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string and match 1+ times a char a-zA-Z followed by a space and make it optional `(?:[a-zA-Z]+ )?` if you want to match all the examples

The append a group around all the alternations.

If you don't need all the capturing groups, you could make them non capturing `(?:` instead except for the numbers that you want to keep.

The values are in group 1.

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z]+ )?((?:\d{11}|\d{14})|(?:\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\-\d{2}|\d{3}\d{3}\d{3}\-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}\.\d{3}.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{2}\d{3}\d{3}\d{4}-\d{2})\b)
```

Note for Java to double escape the backslashes.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SCYny3/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/csL9kW)

---

To get only 3 matches, you could use

```
^[a-zA-Z]+ ((?:\d{11}|\d{14})|(?:\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\-\d{2}|\d{3}\d{3}\d{3}\-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}\.\d{3}.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{2}\d{3}\d{3}\d{4}-\d{2})\b)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CMufdu/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/CrdREv)

Comment: thanks for helping! This will exclude lines not starting with text, but will not remove the text from the final result, now for example I get the `Testing 42702434884` as final result, is there a way to retrieve only the `42702434884`?

Comment: Checked your Java example, there is just one adjustement I was not able to perform, the `05.994.401/0001-53` should not appear, since it does not starts with text (not numbers)

Comment: @nullptr That is the example pattern I had in the first answer. `^[a-zA-Z]+ ((?:\d{11}|\d{14})|(?:\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\-\d{2}|\d{3}\d{3}\d{3}\-\d{2})|(?:\d{2}\.\d{3}.\d{3}\/\d{4}-\d{2}|\d{2}\d{3}\d{3}\d{4}-\d{2})\b)` See https://regex101.com/r/CMufdu/1 See this Java demo https://ideone.com/CrdREv

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't quite clear how you wanted the numbers parsed.  Does this work for you?

1. First it filters only lines starting with text.
2. Then it removes all characters up to the first digit.
3. And stores them in an array.

```java
      String[] lines = {
            "Testing 42702434884", "Testing 064352729-13", "05.994.401/0001-53",
            "Testing 134.632.125-03"
      };

      String[] filtered =
            Arrays.stream(lines).filter(k -> k.matches("^\\D+.*")).map(
                  s -> s.replaceAll("(^\\D+)", "")).toArray(String[]::new);

      for (String s : filtered) {
         System.out.println(s);
      }
```

The above prints

```
42702434884
064352729-13
134.632.125-03
```